# React-Redux update and redirect logic

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have data structures Student, Class and Registrant. Registrant is the link between Class and Student:

```
Registrant 
-----------
StudentId
ClassId
```

I also have an auxiliary data source when you can pick from - call it PotentialStudents.

An end user can browse the list of PotentialStudents, and register them for a class.

If a Student record does not exist for the PotentialStudent record, I need to create one, otherwise I need get the fetched record. I can know this because the PotentialStudentId is a field in Student, but there is no true relation between Student and PotentialStudent - they come from different databases and are actually different data shapes.

Anyways, this is all to setup my question.  I need a function to "createOrFetchStudent", and then I send them on to the RegistrationDetail form.

My question, is how should this be done in react-redux?

I could -

**Try to dispatch the save/fetch and have it signal when it's done, and then redirect, but it gets kind of messy**

```
let student = useSelector(state => state.createdOrFetchedStudent);

useEffect(() => {
  if(student) {
    location.push("/registration", {studentId: student.id});
  }
}, [student]); 

onRegisterDetailClick = (potentialStudent) => {
  // redux-thunk action that does multiple API calls
  dispatch(createOrFetchStudent(potentialStudent));
}
```

**Or do all the work from the action?**

```
onRegisterDetailClick = (potentialStudent) => {
  dispatch(createOrFetchStudentAndThenRedirect(potentialStudent));
}
```

But don't know if it's Ok to be using location in a redux action.

Other thoughts I had -

**I could pass a callback to the action**

```
onRegisterDetailClick = (potentialStudent) => {
  dispatch(createOrFetchStudent(
    potentialStudent,
    (student) => { location.push("/registration", { studentId: student.id } ); })
  );
}
```

**I could return the dipatched data from the thunk method and await it**

```
onRegisterDetailClick = async (potentialStudent) => {
  let student = await dispatch(createOrFetchStudent(potentialStudent));
  location.push("/registration", { studentId: student.id } ); }
}
```

None of these solutions seems very good. Are any of these solutions acceptable or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your action creators pure functions is a good idea (although it is not strictly required like for reducers).
It will improve testability and make your code easier to understand. Putting the side effects (like location change) into thunks is totally valid (your last example).
If you still don't feel comfortable with that (i kinda understand why) you can try utilise redux-saga which will allow you to manage all side effects in one place and keep your functions pure.
You can read more about each approach in redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned I'm using redux-thunk. The weird thing is just identifying this created or fetched record afterwards.

Comment: Yes as i said i feel your pain, maybe someone with more experience with redux-thunk will come up with something better. For me your last example looks like the best bet. (most of them are valid except maybe the first one which a bit too messy)

Comment: I have the last example working now, but I have never seen anyone do this - get value from action rather than state - so I don't know if it's a good call.

Comment: What about fetching student data (existence) on component load. Then when user clicks you already know where to redirect them.